# Can't resolve all parameters for PlatformService: ([object Object], ?, [object Object])

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have two services: `PlatformService` and `AccountService`:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {AccountService} from "./account.service";
import {ToastService} from "./toast.service";
@Injectable()
export class PlatformService {
  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private accountSvc: AccountService,
    private toastSvc: ToastService
  ) {}
  //...
}


import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {ToastService} from "./toast.service";
@Injectable()
export class AccountService {
  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private toastService: ToastService
  ){}
  //...
}
```

And this is the `providers` in `app.module.ts`:

```
providers: [
  StatusBar,
  SplashScreen,
  ToastService,
  AccountService,
  PlatformService,
  SocketService,
  ModelService,
  {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
]
```

I want to inject `accountService` into my `platformService`, but I got the following error:

> Can't resolve all parameters for PlatformService: ([object Object], ?, [object Object]).

I don't think there is a circular dependency in my code, maybe it's because `platformService` and `accountService` both inject `http` and `toastService`?

After I commented `private accountSvc: AccountService,` in the constructor of `PlatformService`, this error disappeared.

Comment: How are you adding them in `providers`

Comment: Question updated, thanks. @Skeptor

Comment: This looks perfect to me, are you sure the imports are fine , correct path

Comment: are you using barrel files to import the providers. `export * from ...` and importing the service from that file

Comment: I'm sure my imports are correct, Webstorm didn't give me any error or warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the error. I imported `RoomPreparePage` in `AccountService`, 
and I also added `AccountService` in the constructor of `RoomPreparePage`, so this seems to be a circular dependency. (However, I didn't add `RoomPreparePage` in the constructor of `AccountService`, I just used it in one of the methods of `AccountService`.)

After I remove the usage of `RoomPreparePage` in `AccountService`, this problem was fixed.